# Java Server/Client for two computers

Tags: java, sockets, serversocket

I am creating a chat between multiple computers, but i cannot find **how to connect a socket to a serverSocket** that **is not in the client's computer**.

P.S. I am new of socket programming.

---

This is server

```
package chat;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Server {

    public List<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
    public HashMap<String, Socket> sockets = new HashMap<String, Socket>();
    public HashMap<String, BufferedReader> inputs = new HashMap<String, BufferedReader>();
    public HashMap<String, PrintWriter> outputs = new HashMap<String, PrintWriter>();

    public void start() throws IOException {
        int port = 2019;
        ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);

        System.out.println("Server started");
        while(true) {
            System.out.println("\nLooking for new channels in the subspace.");
            Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
            BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
            PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()), true);

            System.out.println("Someone connected.");

            new Thread() {
                public void run() {
                    //various input/output operations
                }
            }.start();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Server server = new Server();
        server.start();
    }
}
```

---

this is Client

```
package chat;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class Client {

    public Socket socket;
    public BufferedReader input;
    public PrintWriter output;

    public void start() throws IOException {
        String host = "192.168.1.4 / 127.0.0.1 / computer's global ip";
        int port = 2019;
        socket = new Socket(host, port);
        input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
        output = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()), true);

        System.out.println("Successfully established connection to " + host + ":" + port);

        new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                //output operations
            }
        }.start();

        new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                //input operations
            }
        }.start();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Client client = new Client();
        client.start();
    }
}
```

---

Now, the problem is that **this works when server and client are on the same pc**.
I sent to my other computer a copy of the client file but when i insert the ip of the server's computer (192.168.1.4) nothing happens.
Both computers are connected **to the same WI-FI**.

Another question is: how to connect 2 computers without the same WI-FI?

Comment: Your router has to allow communication between the machines, which might be disabled in your router's settings. Your machine has to allow connections on port 2019, so you might have to create a rule in your firewall (or disable it).

Comment: I created a firewall rule for the jar files on both computers, however that does not work yet.

Answer (score 0):

After 2 years I have enought knowledge about this, so I will answer to help anyone with similar problems.
The problem is not Java, that client-server code should work.
If it doesn't, the problem is the network: if the server is connected to a router (which usually is) then there is no way to access it directly (it doesn't have a public IP itself, but only a local IP; the public IP used is the router's IP). So you need to connect to do "port forwarding", that is telling your router that any connection to a given port has to be sent to 192.168.1."x" local IP. This is handheld by the NAT.

TLDR
Learn about port forwarding and public/private IPs.

Comment: You should provide the solution